# Kitchen Cabinet Materials with lowest emission, Vocs, etc

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, carpentry

What are the kitchen cabinet materials which have Low Air Gas toxic emission, (low VOCs, low formaldehyde) ? I see different material types: Solid Wood, Veneer, MDF, Laminate, plywood, metal, Melamine, Thermofoil. I know it partly depends on manufacturer, but in general is there a ranking of materials which have lowest emission?

Comment: Solid wood, unfinished, is about as good as it gets. Metal, unfinished or with baked enamel would be the only competition from your list.

Comment: Have to agree nothing better than solid wood and even natural hand rubbed wax can provide a beautiful finish that is awesome, wax takes a little up keep compared to finishes with VOC’s but is you want to go with the lowest go natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naturally-grown materials (solid wood) will have less VOC than man-made materials (MDF, melamine, etc.) The more ground-up the middle of the sheet of stock is, the more glue, therefore typically the more VOC.

Note that being veneered is a construction method, not a material (it means a thin layer of nice material is laid over a think core of stronger and cheaper but uglier material).

Having worked in a cabinet shop for some 20 years and been on jobs where low VOC was a specification, the 'types' of cabinet materials listed in the question aren't detailed enough to get low- or no-VOC cabinetry. Simply getting plywood instead of MDF or melamine won't be enough. Plywood and other materials can have varying levels of VOC depending on source. Even solid wood, theoretically no-VOC, may have been finished with heavy-VOC lacquer, or has been kept with other VOC-emitting materials in the same warehouse and has absorbed some for later re-emitting.

You'll need to specify low or no VOC for your supplier, who will probably have to be a custom cabinet maker to get access to the materials. Big-box stores might be able to get specialized sources.

Comment: I agree but for custom work hand polished wax is a no voc finish that looks good